# Trying to understand object oriented programming. How to use object composing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Be the two classes `Point()` and `Circle()` defined below:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self._y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self._x}, {self._y}"

    def move(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        return self._x, self._y


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius, x, y):
        self._radius = radius
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, x, y):
        Point.move(self, x, y)

    def __repr__(self):

        return f"radius = {self._radius}, \nx = {self.x},\ny = {self.y}"


point1 = Point(12, 3)
print(point1)
point1.y = 0
print(point1)

point1.move(55, 7)
print(point1)

circle1 = Circle(4, 1, 1)
print(circle1)
circle1.move(2, 2)
print(circle1)
```

I've tried to develop the method `move(x,y)` in the Circle calling the method move(x,y) from the class Point, without using inheritance. Firstly an object was initialized:

```
circle1 = Circle(4,1,1)
```

but when you use `circle1.move(2,2)` the circle position is still (1,1): What is wrong?
I want to use _x and _y to simulates private variables!

Comment: Have you compared `circle1.x` to `circle1._x`? Also, while I assume this is just arbitrary example code, it's worth pointing out that using properties as you are here is an bad practice in Python.

Comment: you don't need setter/getter functions in python. this is not java :)

Comment: You probably wanted to have `self.center = Point(x, y)` instead of `self.x = x ; self.y = y`

Comment: There is no advantage to having a ``property`` when all it does is give read/write access to a hidden attribute. Just directly use ``x`` and ``y`` attributes. The point of ``property`` is that you can add getter/setter *if needed* without breaking the appearance of attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem there is that you are not using "composition" - you are just randomly calling `Point.move` from within a method in your circle class. That call will fail, as it would fail if placed anywhere else: `Point.move` is an instance method, and it needs an instance of point to work on.

For "composition" you need to have instances of the other class that are attributes on your class - and then you call upon the methods on those instances when required.

For example, your "Circle" could have a ".center" attribute that is a point. And then, you just call `circle.center.move` in an instance - or, if you want a `.move` method in the circle class itself:

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius, x, y):
        self._radius = radius
        self.center = Point(x, y)

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.center.move(x, y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Circle center at ({self.point}), radius: {self.radius}"
```

## What you were trying to do

Your code attempted to call a method in `Point` passing an instance of `Circle`. While Python 3 allows this, it is a sheer coincidence that it almost worked (if the "x" and "y" names in Circle where the same as in "Point" it would have worked as it is demonstrated in Dani's answer) - but that is not "OOP" nor "Composition", and just does not raise a runtime error because Python 3 treats instance methods in classes just as functions.

A "circle" is not a "point". Thinking about geometry, you could say that "Circle" and "Point" partake some attributes and methods - Python allow you to share those by using multiple inheritance, and what we call "mixins" - - So you could have a "LocationMixin"  class thatwould have the "x" and "y" attributes, and the "move" method and be an ancestor of both "Point" and "Circle", and that would work.

## Simplifying code

Your composition problem apart, it is important to note that in Python it is not important to try to make attributes  "private", and define getters and setters for public consunption - 
Your point class would work just as well if it is simply written as:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.x}, {self.y}"

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return self.x, self.y
```

The getter and setter will make sense if you want to validate that x and y ae set to numbers, or validate value ranges - otherwise, they are just redundant.

An interesting thing is that Python designs its "properties" so that you can change the attributes to have the getters and setters and add these validations on a later point, without breaking any compatibility with the previous versions of the class (Point) .

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Circle` class to:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius, x, y):
        self._radius = radius
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def move(self, x, y):
        Point.move(self, x, y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"radius = {self._radius}, \nx = {self._x},\ny = {self._y}"
```

**Example**

```
circle1 = Circle(4, 1, 1)
print(circle1)
circle1.move(2, 2)
print(circle1)
```

**Output**

```
radius = 4, 
x = 1,
y = 1
radius = 4, 
x = 2,
y = 2
```

Otherwise, when `Point.move` is executed two new fields (`_x, _y`) are created, see:

```
circle1 = Circle(4, 1, 1)
circle1.move(2, 2)
print(circle1._x, circle1._y)
```

**Output**

```
2 2
```

Comment: you made `_x` and `_y` "private" - which is not a good practice in the language, but made nothing to fix the problem of calling a class method in instance with an instance of the unrelated Circle as if itshould work - it is just a coincidence that it works.

Comment: @jsbueno It is not a coincidence. Every Python class method receives self as the first parameter, if the passed self object has the fields the method needs to work it will work. If it walks like a duck, it is a duck...

Answer (score 1):

You are not manipulating the right variable.
You circle class uses `self.x` and `self.y` but in the call to `Point.move(self, x, y)` you manipulate `self._x` and `self._y` instead

Comment: It is correct. How can I use _x and _y all over de code?

Comment: @Laurinda Souza See Dani Mesejo 's answer. Just change self.x in the __init__() of circle to self._x (same for y)

Answer (score 1):

@jsbueno has the most design-wise correct answer. If you go ahead and use Point.move() you are using move() as a static method, instead of an instance method. That will pass the Circle 'self' object to the Point.move() method. If you follow the suggestions of the other posts to change self.x to self._x etc. it will work but it is a very bad design. It works because it treats the 'self' variable inside Point as a third argument along with x and y, instead of the actual Point object. You can rewrite for example your Point.move() method to something like this that would would still be working for moving the Circle object, but is badly designed:

```
def move2(foo,x,y):
    foo._x = x
    foo._y = y
    print(foo._x,foo._y)
    return foo._x,foo._y
```

Also the following is a link where I found the difference in static methods vs class methods while trying to answer your question :)
[CLASS METHOD VS STATIC METHOD 2020](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_differences_between_static_method_and_class_method_instance_method.php)